# How to know when Parse.initialize() has already been called?

Tags: java, parse-platform

Right now I am using a static boolean to tell when the initialization has occurred. Is there an easier way to know that I have already called initialize?

Thank you!!!

SOLVED!!!! Thank you so much for your comments. You need to initialize parse in a class that extends an application, and then add it to the manifest file as an application (not an other activity).

:)

---

This is my class to use Parse:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import com.parse.Parse;

import android.app.Application;

public class UseParse extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
Parse.initialize(this, "id", "key");
 }
}
```

---

This is my android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
 >


 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
      android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>


 <supports-screens 
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true"/>



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false" />


<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name ="com.example.myapp.UseParse"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
     //... more



    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
     <category android:name="com.example.myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>




</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What's `Parse.initialize()`?

Comment: Parse.initialize(this, "id", "key"); It is called in my app that that I can gather information from Parse.com and query my data.

Comment: It's number 2 under what I need to do to connect my app to parse. [link](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make a Application Class and in onCreate initialize parse.

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, "id","key");
    }
}
```

After this it wont be called again and again.

Also declare it in your manifest

```
<application
    android:name="com.you.yourapp.YourApplication "
```

EDIT: This is the only place where you initialize it. And not in the Login Activity or anywhere else.

Comment: My application starts at my login screen. I still need a way to check if Parse is initialized... so I don't try to initialize it again.

Comment: Go through the tutorial again...
It says "STEP 2:Call Parse.initialize from the onCreate method of your Application class to set your application id and client key"

Application Class not Activity Class. 

So do not initialize parse in your login screen , instead make application class and initialize it over there.

Comment: Agree with engico. You have to do as he showed. I have used Parse in two of my apps now. It's a cakewalk to use it. :)

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! I posted my final code to help other people out that were having the same problems as me. I realized now that I had the wrong way of thinking about it. I should have initialized Parse as an Application and not an activity. Thank you again!!!!

Answer (score 8):

If you, like me, for some reason can not use custom Application class, just surround the `init` method with try/catch, like this:

```
private void initParse() {
    try {
        Parse.initialize(getApplication(), "some id here", "another id here");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That way it won't crash the whole app, and the SDK will still work, tested it.