# StartActivity - Android

Tags: android

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UL62rAd.png]

I'm facing a problem in starting an activity in Android.

**What am i doing?**

I have a setOnClickListner in *SignUpActivity.class* which calls a method called "DoSignUp" located in *MethodsParse.class.*

**What does this "DoSignUp" do?**

It literally does the signUp using the values receveid from parameters.
But, as i'm using Parse library and Parse has an exclusive method to do SignUps: "signUpInBackground()", i don't know what to do.

**What trouble am i facing?**

When i try to do the signUp as an existing User, it works fine (shows me the Toast with: Something went wrong...)!

When i try to do the signUp as a new User,  it shows me a error: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/swFdzcl.png]

**But**, I tried to debug my app, and when i tried to do the signUp as a new User, the data from it goes to Database, it means, my problem is on startActivity... but i don't know why.

Comment: I see some problems 1) Remove 'extends Activity' from MethodsParse, you use it as a regular Java object, hence it should not extend Activity 2) Looks like you initialize Parse inside MethodsParse. This should be done in an 'extends Application' object, see this link: https://parse.com/questions/should-developers-call-parseinitialize-in-oncreate-of-every-activity-android

Comment: About the initializing of Parse... I do it through the static method called "Initalize" in MethodsParse.class in my SplashScreen activity inside my onCreate.

Comment: About the removing of extends Activity... if i do that, shows me an error: http://i.imgur.com/rdGuKOe.png

Comment: You really should do `Parse.initialize()` in an Application class. This SO answer might be more clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026185/how-to-know-when-parse-initialize-has-already-been-called

Comment: @cYrixmorten it is in my Application class: http://i.imgur.com/nqgXLJk.png

Comment: `AppCompat(Activity)` .. it is an `Activity`, not an `Application` .. this means  that once you move to another Activity you would have to repeat the `Parse.initialize()` procedure. You avoid this by following my advice.

Comment: @cYrixmorten now i'm getting 'the invalid session token parse'.. should i open a new question?

Comment: @cYrixmorten.. just fix it... it was cause when i deleted all my test users.. i didn't do the .logOut()... so they was still in the phone's memory.

Comment: Please post actual code / error messages instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: @Pang, sorry.. didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problems

1. Remove `extends Activity` from MethodsParse, you use it as a regular Java object, hence it should not extend Activity
2. Looks like you initialize Parse inside MethodsParse. This should be done in an `extends Application` object, see: https://parse.com/questions/should-developers-call-parseinitialize-in-oncreate-of-every-activity-android or [How to know when Parse.initialize() has already been called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026185/how-to-know-when-parse-initialize-has-already-been-called)

Looking at your error I strongly believe 1) to be the cause of your error. You call `startActivity(..,..)` and the method `startActivity()` is only available because you extend Activity. The problem is, since you call the login method directly from another activity `MethodsParse` has not started it's lifecycle (by the OS calling `onCreate()`), making `startActivity()` fail as it has no context.

Long answer short, change:

```
startActivity(..,..)
```

To:

```
currentCtx.startActivity(..,..)
```

Comment: I think the problem, as you mention, is on the lifecycle... but how can i call startActivity if i remove the extends Activity from MethodsParse?

Comment: Either do as I write in my answer, use the parameter context `currentCtx.startActivity(..,..)`, or even simpler, move the signup method to  `SignUpActivity`, then `startActivity(SignUpActivity.this, NextActivity.class)` will work

Comment: I tried to do what you told me:
1 - Remove extends... 2 - get the currentCtx and .startActivity passing an intent passed as parameter... didn't worked.http://prntscr.com/8xo6mv

Answer (score 0):

The exception is `nullpointerexception`, one of the variable that you are passing is `null`. This error could be due to `nextClass` or `currentCtx` is `null`.

Comment: it isn't null.. i debuged, and the values are corrects

Comment: well, to be fair .. it IS null. However neither nextClass or currentCtx, but rather the missing context of `MethodsParse` as I tried to explain in my answer.